# How to give a parameter an interface in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, function, parameters, interface

How can we let the function know what to expect from a parameter in a function?

For instance, the `kind` parameter can only have either "STATIC", "FIELD", "ARG" or "VAR" (one of those four). Is there any way to implement it?

```py
# imaginary implementation

def define(name, type, kind: Kind): #something like this
    #do something

# call the function
define("foo", "INT", "KIND") # the "KIND" part emits error when the function is
                             # declared because it can only have either 
                             # "STATIC", "FIELD", "ARG", "VAR"
```

So later if anyone wants to implement the function `define`, they will know what they need to(or can) pass as `kind`

Comment: so `Kind` should be an [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Enum)?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist can I use `Enum` to specify a parameter's candidates?

Comment: i put a the link to the documentation in my comment. as i am not entirely sure what you want i suggest you have a look at the doc an see if that fits your needs.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist When I checked before, I tried to implement it using Enum, but it didn't work. Maybe I need to give more tweaks to make it work as I want. Thanks a lot for your time.